# PyInstaller using old non-existant code that’s been changed

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have a script that generates logs based on an equation. Initially I had no equation so it printed out “0”. I run the script through my IDE, the equation works. I compiled with PyInstaller, run it, it’s all the same, except the log is back to printing “0”.

Any idea what the cause could be?

Answer (score 2):

I just spent quite some time struggling with the same problem, but found a solution. I know it's a bit late, but I'm leaving this for people who may find this useful in the future.

I have just found out that I had two versions of the folder containing my script: one of them was the one I was actively working with, and the other one was an outdated version whose existence I didn't even remember. Turns out PyInstaller was importing the outdated version instead of the one I was working with.

I figured this out by looking at the .toc files inside the build folder. I searched the 'Analysis-00.toc' file for my script, and found out that it was importing the wrong one. I deleted the wrong outdated script, cleaned all the pyinstaller files and created a new build. After that, it worked as it should.

Answer (score 0):

I simply deleted the "build" folder, I think it had cached something and forcing pyinstaller to rebuild the whole thing worked for me.